# Quaternion To Direction Vector

Tags: c++, vector, quaternions

I am attempting to convert my Quaternion to a direction vector so that I can move my camera in the direction it is facing. I read that you can convert your quaternion to a rotation matrix first then get the direction so I tried that.

```
inline Matrix4<float> ToRotationMatrix() {
    Vector3<float> forward = Vector3<float>( 2.0f * ( GetX() * GetZ() - GetW() * GetY() ), 2.0f * ( GetY() * GetZ() + GetW() * GetX() ), 1.0f - 2.0f * ( GetX() * GetX() + GetY() * GetY() ) );
    Vector3<float> up = Vector3<float>( 2.0f * ( GetX() * GetY() + GetW() * GetZ() ), 1.0f - 2.0f * ( GetX() * GetX() + GetZ() * GetZ() ), 2.0f * ( GetY() * GetZ() - GetW() * GetX() ) );
    Vector3<float> right = Vector3<float>( 1.0f - 2.0f * ( GetY() * GetY() + GetZ() * GetZ() ), 2.0f * ( GetX() * GetY() - GetW() * GetZ() ), 2.0f * ( GetX() * GetZ() + GetW() * GetY() ) );

    return Matrix4<float>().InitRotationFromVectors( forward, up, right );
}

inline Matrix4<T> InitRotationFromVectors( const Vector3<T> &n, const Vector3<T> &v, const Vector3<T> &u ) {
    Matrix4<T> ret = Matrix4<T>().InitIdentity();

    ret[ 0 ][ 0 ] = u.GetX();
    ret[ 1 ][ 0 ] = u.GetY();
    ret[ 2 ][ 0 ] = u.GetZ();

    ret[ 0 ][ 1 ] = v.GetX();
    ret[ 1 ][ 1 ] = v.GetY();
    ret[ 2 ][ 1 ] = v.GetZ();

    ret[ 0 ][ 2 ] = n.GetX();
    ret[ 1 ][ 2 ] = n.GetY();
    ret[ 2 ][ 2 ] = n.GetZ();

    return ret;
}

inline Vector3<float> GetForward( const Matrix4<float> &rotation ) const {
    return Vector3<float>( rotation[ 2 ][ 0 ], rotation[ 2 ][ 1 ], rotation[ 2 ][ 2 ] );
}
```

When my camera is facing forward it moves in the correct direction but when  I turn it the camera starts moving in incorrect directions. The camera rotates like so.

```
void Camera::Rotate( const Vector3<float> &axis, float angle ) {
    Rotate( Quaternion( axis, angle ) );
}

void Camera::Rotate( const Quaternion &quaternion ) {
    m_rotation = Quaternion( ( quaternion * m_rotation ).Normalized() );
}
```

And to multiply those quaternions....

```
inline Quaternion operator*( const Quaternion &quat ) const {
    Quaternion ret;

    ret[ 3 ] = ( ( *this )[ 3 ] * quat[ 3 ] ) - ( ( *this )[ 0 ] * quat[ 0 ] ) - ( ( *this )[ 1 ] * quat[ 1 ] ) - ( ( *this )[ 2 ] * quat[ 2 ] );
    ret[ 0 ] = ( ( *this )[ 3 ] * quat[ 0 ] ) + ( ( *this )[ 0 ] * quat[ 3 ] ) + ( ( *this )[ 1 ] * quat[ 2 ] ) - ( ( *this )[ 2 ] * quat[ 1 ] );
    ret[ 1 ] = ( ( *this )[ 3 ] * quat[ 1 ] ) + ( ( *this )[ 1 ] * quat[ 3 ] ) + ( ( *this )[ 2 ] * quat[ 0 ] ) - ( ( *this )[ 0 ] * quat[ 2 ] );
    ret[ 2 ] = ( ( *this )[ 3 ] * quat[ 2 ] ) + ( ( *this )[ 2 ] * quat[ 3 ] ) + ( ( *this )[ 0 ] * quat[ 1 ] ) - ( ( *this )[ 1 ] * quat[ 0 ] );

    return ret;
}
```

Note: Quaternion[ 0 ] is x, Quaternion[ 1 ] is y, Quaternion[ 2 ] is z and Quaternion[ 3 ] is w.

I have been struggling with this for weeks and I am out of ideas of what could be wrong. If anybody has any ideas or suggestions on why this works or other ways to do it it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just multiply a unit vector by the Quaternion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's rephrase what you want to do: you have a representation of the camera's position in the global frame, `G_p1`, and want to move it forward in its own frame by an amount `C_t = [0;0;1]` (here, `G_` prefix means global frame, `C_` means camera).

We want to compute `G_p2 = G_p1 + G_t`. We need to write `G_t` in terms of `C_t`.

We can write this as `G_t = G_R_C C_t`, where `G_R_C` is the rotation matrix describing the rotation from the camera to the global frame. Writing this as a function of your quaternion `q`, you just need to compute `G_t = G_R_C(q) C_t` and add it to the position. Because `C_t = [0;0;1]`, you can see that `G_t` is the last column of `G_R_C(q)`. You're using the last row, not the last column.